# Position div atop its parent

Tags: html, css

I want to position a child div above its parent as the following image shows:

[image: child and parent]

The child has no fixed height.

Relevant code:

```
<footer id="parent">
    <div id="child" v-if="composing">
        <img src="/img/typing-indicator.gif" alt="typing" />
        <span>User is typing...</span>
    </div>
    <div id="input-container">
         .....
    </div>    
</footer>
```

Comment: `position: relative` on the parent element, `position: absolute` on the child element, and `top: -value`, where value is the arbitrary number you need to set it to. A better solution would be to structure the DOM in the way you need, rather than trying to fight against the document flow. Also, is the child element's height going to be dynamic?

Comment: [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866804/position-children-div-above-parent-div?rq=1), and [perhaps this fiddle may help you](http://jsfiddle.net/5JZGg/76/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to parent and `position: absolute;` & `bottom: 100%` to child

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 20px
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <footer class="parent">
    parent
    <div class="child" v-if="composing">
        child
    </div> 
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-top` to negative of its height (for example `30px`):

```
.child{
    margin-top:-30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` on the child and `position: relative` on the parent , something like that should work:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: XXXX;
  height: XXXX; 
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: XXXX;
  height: XXXX; 
}
```

You can also use transform property on the position absolute child:

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  left: 0;
  width: XXXX;
  height: XXXX; 
}
```

Comment: This solution is almost good except `bottom: 100%` should be used instead of negative `top` value. `top: -100%;` means that children will be laid as many pixels above the paren as the parent height is - e.g. if parent height is `100px` then children's top edge would start `100px` above the parent. 

DEMO of `bottom: 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/ds3kvz28/
DEMO of `top: -100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/ds3kvz28/1/